# Why is the size of img(te1,te2) is bigger than the input image?

Tags: matlab

Suppose `edge` is the output of an image edge detection function. I need your help to understand why - when I use `size(...)` to check the size of `img(te1, te2)`, I obtain a size bigger `(1467  1467)` than that of the input image `(128  128)`. What can I do to achieve the same size of `(128  128`) when I do `size(img(te1, te2))`

Here is the situation:

```
img = imread('LENNA128.bmp');  %% input image 
edgemap = double(255-edge);    
[te1,te2] = find(edgemap==255);
img(te1,te2)= 125;

imshow(uint8(img(te1,te2)))
imshow(uint8(edgemap))
size(img(te1,te2))
size(edgemap)
```

Many thanks for your replies.

Comment: Can you show a complete example? We should be able to run any code you post!

Comment: Does `img(edgemap==255) = 125;` instead of `find(...)` and `img(te1,te2)...` solve your problem?

Comment: The edge detection function can be downloaded here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20997-image-edge-detection-using-ant-colony-optimization

Comment: @hbaderts Yes, it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Happy2016 I added an answer with some explanation. I hope this makes clear why you ran into this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` function returns two vectors `te1` and `te2` which correspond to the column and row. Let's look at a small example:

```
x = [ 1, 2, 3 ;
      3, 1, 2 ;
      2, 3, 1 ]

[row,col] = find(x==3)
```

which will return

```
row = [2; 3; 1];
col = [1; 2; 3];
```

i.e. there are three's at `(2,1)`, `(3,2)` and `(1,3)`, which is indeed correct. The next step you do is the indexing, which returns

```
x(row,col)
ans =
     3     1     2
     2     3     1
     1     2     3
```

This is definitely not what you wanted. The reason is, MATLAB interprets this as: "Take row 2, then row 1, then row 3, and for each of these rows: take col 1, then col 2, then col 3." That's what it returns:

```
ans = 
     second row of x
     first row of x
     third row of x
```

To get only the exact elements you need, you can e.g. use the [`sub2ind`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function, which creates the [*linear* index](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) of the specified `(row,column)` pairs:

```
x(sub2ind(size(x),row,col)) = 4
x =
     1     2     4
     4     1     2
     2     4     1
```

so all occurences of `3` are replaced by `4`.

---

A simpler, faster alternative is by directly comparing `x` to 3 with `x==3`. This returns a logical array, which is `1` everywhere, where `x` is 3:

```
x==3
ans =
     0     0     1
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
```

you can use this to index `x`:

```
x(x==3) = 4
x =
     1     2     4
     4     1     2
     2     4     1
```

---

You can do exactly this: compare `edgemap` to 255, and use this to index the image:

```
img(edgemap==255) = 125;
```